# Session replication on tomcat 7 without multicast

Tags: tomcat, session-replication

Is it possible to enable replicate sessions between tomcat instances running in completely independent environments, without using multicast?

1. I already checked JDBC-based session manager, however it only saves swapped sessions so fresh sessions are missing.
2. https://code.google.com/p/memcached-session-manager/ is not working for me (e.g. it confuses cookies when having multiple apps on the same tomcat) and it flushes sessions from memcache as soon as one tomcat is restarted. I thinks this is the best solution, but I guess the fix will take time.

Is there an alternative without using multicast? Performance is not relevant.

Comment: I used the JDBC-based session manager with a short timeout somewhere to ensure fairly timely saving of sessions, 300-600 seconds. I accepted that the user might lose a few minutes' worth of state in a failover. It worked well enough as initially set up, so I never revisited it, and the site is now long gone. The multicast-based thing seems a monstrosity to me: every Tomcat instance gets every session whether it needs it or not, so every instance uses maximum session memory.

Answer (score 1):

Almost 10 years after and for Tomcat 9 (last on javax), there does not seem to be much option for TCP based out of the box session replication. [Hazelcast Tomcat Session Manager](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-tomcat-sessionmanager) is a fair option.

For non-out of the box, best way is perhaps to implement [CatalineCluster](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/9.0.x/java/org/apache/catalina/ha/CatalinaCluster.java) interface and provide a custom implementation, which could leverage other messaging infra (e.g. Kafka) at the bottom layer for messaging and cluster management (e.g. Zookeeper).

I have not tried but [DeltaManager](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/cluster-howto.html) probably will scale a bit beyond the 4 Tomcats mentioned.

Implementing anything below CatalinaCluster, e.g. tribes service and transport could be a bit of challenge as tribes is not very well documented.

I am sure you have solved it by some other means and the above will not be very useful to you after all these years. I attempt to document what I found here as there are not many posts discussing Tomcat session replication over TCP.

This is very relevant as cloud providers do not allow multicast in their private networks.